# Configurar Android-Studio para quitar código que no se usa en Android

Tags: android, android-studio

He leído que una solución para evitar llegar al problema del limite de 64k de referencias en código.

Es decir a veces se utiliza una librería pero que solo se usa dos métodos de los cientos que incorpora.

¿Cómo se configura android-studio para reducir y optimizar el apk resultante?

**Edit**

Me encontrado con ese código pero no ser si es para eso, quitar las referencias dentro las dependencias que no se usan.

```
android {
    ...

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Que librería es la que quieres recortar? Google-play-services o alguna así?

Comment: @DanielFaro no se puede indicar todas en global, es decir que coge de las dependencias?

Comment: Yo te lo decia como solución aparte, porque en el propio gradle puedes limitar los imports asi: compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.1" (solo cojo la parte de ads). Eso reduce mucho el numero de referencas.

Comment: @Daniel_Faro interesante lo que comentas

Comment: @Webserveis he agregado una respuesta espero sea de ayuda, para optimizar tu .apk la opción es Proguard como lo comentas, saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buen día,

un proyecto en producción puede llegar a ser muy complejo y no necesariamente puedes tener esas referencias por métodos que no son utilizados en tu aplicación, te lo comento porque aún usando [Sonar](http://www.sonarqube.org/) (Ahora SonarQube) para revisar la calidad del código, en varios de nuestros proyectos es necesario activar el [soporte multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle).

> Quitar código que no se usa en Android Studio.

Recomendaría el uso de [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/) en un proyecto Android ya que su objetivo es que tengas un código con buena calidad, puedes obtener un análisis de tu código y varias métricas que te ayudarían a optimizarlo en todos los aspectos. Puede ayudarte a detectar:

- Bugs potenciales tu código.
- Complejidad innecesaria.
- Comentarios.
- Sugiere estándares apropiados.
- detecta código duplicado, por ejemplo métodos que puedes reutilizar.
- etc...

También puedes usar [Proguard](https://www.google.com.mx/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwierfTEoI_PAhVDwYMKHSBLDMIQFghTMAc&url=http%3A%2F%2Fproguard.sourceforge.net%2Fmanual%2Foptimizations.html&usg=AFQjCNHGaNA5r4u3WNFhhhMTHypJz4I3cw&sig2=ojdsObqJDTSS1OvCJpGGBA) para eliminar clases no necesarias o código que no tiene uso.

Si no usaras SonarQube o [Proguard](https://www.google.com.mx/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwierfTEoI_PAhVDwYMKHSBLDMIQFghTMAc&url=http%3A%2F%2Fproguard.sourceforge.net%2Fmanual%2Foptimizations.html&usg=AFQjCNHGaNA5r4u3WNFhhhMTHypJz4I3cw&sig2=ojdsObqJDTSS1OvCJpGGBA), algo más sencillo que yo realizo es definir `TODO` en tu código que no estas completamente seguro si se usaría posteriormente o lo tienes comentado, de esta forma puedes ver todos los indicadores en la ventana `TODO` y rápidamente puedes identificarlos para eliminarlos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> A veces se utiliza una librería pero que solo se usa dos métodos de
>   los cientos que incorpora.

En cuanto el uso de librerías en un proyecto, supone tener como objetivo facilitar el trabajo, "no volver a inventar la rueda" como alguien me lo acentuó, sin embargo personalmente creo que hay que considerar 2 cosas importantes para decidir si se integra a un proyecto.

- ¿La librería puede funcionar correctamente en todos los Sistemas Operativos? en ocasiones te encuentras sorpresas y te das cuenta que una librería que es amplia mente usada, en un sistema operativo no funciona adecuadamente.
- Evaluar si en verdad esa librería  es necesaria ya que como comentas agregas una librería y solo se usan 2 métodos de cientos, me ha tocado encontrar estos casos en los que por "facilidad" se integra todo un monstruo y en realidad es algo que se puede lograr con un solo método.

En este segundo punto viene a referencia un concepto llamado [Code Bloat](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_inflado), que precisamente se refiere a esto. Es cierto lo de "no volver a reinventar la rueda" pero en ocasiones no es necesario agregar tanto si lo que requerimos puede ser algo muy sencillo y puede ser creado por nosotros mismos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> ¿Cómo se configura android-studio para reducir y optimizar el apk
>   resultante?

En android principalmente se usa **[ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html)** que ademas de optimizar tu aplicación tal vez es más conocido por que también puedes ofuscar el código.

Aquí esta un tutorial en español:

[ProGuard: Optimiza, reduce y ofusca el código de tus aplicaciones Android](https://miguelangellv.wordpress.com/2013/04/23/proguard-optimiza-reduce-y-ofusca-el-codigo-de-tus-aplicaciones-android/)

y este interesante artículo:

[Pon a dieta a tus APKs](https://elbauldelprogramador.com/pon-dieta-tus-apks/)

Comment: Muy buenas Elena, una respuesta perfecta, tengo para días aprender todo los conceptos expuestos +1

Comment: Excelente aporte @Elenasys

Comment: cabe aclarar tambien la importancia de lo que OP dice sobre que solo usa 2 metodos de una libreria completa, por ejemplo, hay librerias como la de firebase que yo uso, que por ejemplo tenes el compile.firebase.google:core que te añade todo lo de firebase , pero si solo necesitas trabajar con la base de datos, no hace falta importar el core donde esta todo sino tratar de buscar el com.firebase.google:database , hay muchas veces que la gente agrega librerias completas cuando no saben que se utilizan de ellas

Comment: Hola Armando buen punto, en el caso de Firebase se puede realizar esto, también lo he visto con [com.google.android.gms](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/packages/), pero la mayoría de las librerias actuales tienes que usar todo el proyecto para poder utilizarla, creo que en un futuro se tendrá esto como característica común en las librerías.

Comment: Buenas, gracias por enlazar mi artículo (Pon a dieta tus APKs) :-)

Comment: @algui91 En verdad es tu blog, muy buenos artículos, lo realizas tu o un grupo de desarrolladores?

Comment: @Elenasys gracias. Es mio, aunque de vez en cuando publico Posts invitados.

Comment: Buenas, he encontrado el siguiente video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5frxLkO4oTM&index=7&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE&linkId=19023506 si quieres añadir dentro de la respuesta

Answer (score 2):

Buen dia , tuve que manejar el mismo problema , mira puedes agregar el dex en tu gradle dependiendo a la version que tengas , aqui te dejo un link

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Tambien el problema de los 64k se debe a que en tus dependencias del gradle estas compilando librerias que ya las tienes agregadas en tu carpeta lib, entonces se compilan 2 veces lo que genera el problema.

Otro problema comun es aue tengas desactualizado las librerias de tu gradle , en dependences .

Otra cosita , el error no va a saltar por la cantidad de lineas de codigo escritas , sino seria medio engorroso tener que seguir un patron de programacion , pero pueses ahorrarte el problema siguiendo el link de arriba , que aunque no sea lo mas viable , sirve lara seguir adelantes, saludos

**NOTA**

En tu app gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true  //Agregar esto
    }
```

Dentro de tu **AndroidManifest**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
        <application
            ...
            android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"> 
            ...
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

Recordar de agregar esta linea dentro de tu oncreate

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    MultiDex.install(this); //Agregar esto dentro de oncreate
    super.onCreate();
}
```

Recorda agregar la dependencia

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

como dice arriba

saludos

Comment: La referencia está inglés con lo que puede que a muchos se les complique entender como solucionar el problema, ¿podrías describir brevemente (si es con un ejemplo mejor) las posibles soluciones que menciona el link?

Comment: Con todo gusto, cuando llegue a casa publico todo en español, estoy desde el cel