# Quitar palabra de un string

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente String `String txt="Formulado=OXICLORURO DE COBRE 35% (exp. en Cu) [WG] P/P,"`
Quiero quitar la parte de `Formulado=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te sugiero un método el cual recibe el texto y la palabra a eliminar y retorna el texto sin la palabra deseada:

```
public String eliminarPalabra(String texto, String palabra){

   return texto.replace(palabra, "");

}
```

puedes usarlo de esta manera:

```
String txt="Formulado=OXICLORURO DE COBRE 35% (exp. en Cu) [WG] P/P,";
String palabra="Formulado=";
System.out.println(eliminarPalabra(txt, palabra));
```

Se obtendría como salida:

```
OXICLORURO DE COBRE 35% (exp. en Cu) [WG] P/P,
```

Comment: Y ¿qué, exactamente, aporta el uso de método? Una llamada de método lo que hace es meter todos los parámetros en el stack, cortar la ejecución, pasar el control al método, ejecutar, meter en el stack el resultado, devolver el control, recuperar el resultado y continuar con la ejecución. ¿Qué aporta esto? A no ser que queramos perder tiempo del procesador... Por la misma le podemos dar la idea de montar una librería que sirve para eliminar contenido de un string. Total, que no está nada claro por qué aconsejas el uso de un método. E, insisto, que no aporta absolutamente nada.

Comment: No soy un experto en Java, pero te puedo comentar que esta respuesta aporta el no pegar código por todos lados de tu programa, ¿Si el OP desea reemplazar más textos en su aplicación?, para un programa grande el uso de métodos aplica para realizar "procesos", en este caso el de eliminar una cadena dentro de un texto. 
El uso de library se debe evaluar, de hecho no me agrada el [Code bloat](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/23746/configurar-android-studio-para-quitar-c%C3%B3digo-que-no-se-usa-en-android/23803#23803)

Answer (score 2):

A ver si te sirve:

```
txt = txt.replace("Formulario=", "");
```

Pero si hubieses buscado un poco lo habrías encontrado tu solo

Comment: Perfecto, gracias!

Comment: Muy bien por la respuesta, ayudo al OP pero creo que el comentario esta de mas

Comment: Puede que no te guste mi comentario, pero esto es java básico tirando a elemental. Cualquiera que se precie debe encontrar estas soluciones por si solo. Lo que pasa es que la gente se acostumbra a pedir la solución y esto no es programar.