# Como arreglar el error al reducir recursos en android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Contrui una aplicación cuyo APK pesa demasiado. Lo raro es que no tiene muchos archivos porque estoy recién empezando a elaborarla. Encontré y utilice el siguiente código que proporciona Android para reducir recursos:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Ahora al construir la app me sale este error:

```
Error while executing: am start -n "com.e_2y.atesur4k.atesurtv/com.e_2y.atesur4k.atesurtv.SplashActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.e_2y.atesur4k.atesurtv/.SplashActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.e_2y.atesur4k.atesurtv/com.e_2y.atesur4k.atesurtv.SplashActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
```

Revise el manifest pero todo esta correcto:

```
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Cual creen que puede ser el problema?

Comment: Proguard elimina clases que determina no necesitas y por lo general elimina clases de mas. Vas a tener que agregarle reglas al archivo de configuración para que no elimine esta clase por ejemplo. Probablemente haya más cosas que tengas que configurar. https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/examples

Comment: Cuando dices que el APK pesa demasiado, a que tamaño te refieres?

Comment: la apk tiene un tamaño de 55mb, solo tiene codigo no le puse aun ninguna imagen solamente un gif de 1.5mb

Comment: @ElmerYucra que tamaño tiene el directorio /build al construir tu proyecto? :)

Comment: @Elenasys en el link puedes ver el resultado del analizador de apk https://ibb.co/fnDbJZ0

Comment: @ElmerYucra definitivamente libxwalk es lo que causa que tu .apk tenga un tamaño considerable, son más de 43 mb, de hecho son módulos de c (.so) código nativo, si usas esta library y es necesaria puedes separar tu apk por arquitecturas: https://proandroiddev.com/reducing-apk-size-by-using-abi-filters-and-apk-split-74a68a885f4e

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Este error que señalas:

```
Error type 3
Error: Activity class ...  does not exist.
```

sucede regularmente cuando habilitas:

```
    shrinkResources true
    minifyEnabled true
```

indica que no existe una `Activity` en tu proyecto, la cual seguramente si se encuentra en el paquete

```
com.e_2y.atesur4k.atesurtv.SplashActivity
```

**En este caso te sugiero limpiar el proyecto y construirlo nuevamente o eliminar los directorios `/build` y construir nuevamente tu proyecto, con eso debe ser suficiente.**

---

> el apk pesaba demasiado y lo raro es que no tiene muchos archivos por
>   que estoy recién empezando a elaborarla

La principal causa de esto es el [Code Bloat](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_inflado) debido a las dependencias que definimos en nuestro proyecto, ejemplo:

```
dependencies {   

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.16.'
    implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.chuck:library:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.2.1'

}
```

En ocasiones como desarrolladores buscamos determinada library para solucionar alguna tarea pero esto ocasiona que agreguemos código innecesario en el proyecto que en la mayoría de los casos no va a ser utilizado y que en ocasiones esta funcionalidad se puede realizar mediante las clases del Android SDK.

Tu proyecto puede no tener muchos archivos como comentas, pero posiblemente si revisas dentro del directorio `/build`, este podría tener un tamaño considerable comparado con el que tiene tu proyecto sin este directorio, esto es debido a las dependencias que usas en tu proyecto.

Como una opción te sugiero instalar el "android Size Analyzer" que es un plugin de Android Studio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que [te ayudara a analizar y de esta forma reducir el tamaño de tu app](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size?hl=es), esto lo puedes revisar en el documento oficial:

[**Reduce el tamaño de tu app**](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size?hl=es)

Que te indica estas practicas:

- [Reduce el tamaño y la cantidad de recursos, quitando recursos que no se usan.](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size?hl=es#reduce-resources)
- [Minimiza el uso de recursos de la biblioteca ( Libraries)](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size?hl=es#minimize).
- [Usa gráficos vectoriales](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size?hl=es#vector).
- [Procesa los archivos .PNG mediante compresión al compilar.](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size?hl=es#crunch)
- [Comprime los archivos .PNG y .JPEG](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size?hl=es#compress)
- [Reduce el código nativo y Java](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size?hl=es#reduce-code).
- [Conserva varios APK de menor tamaño](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size?hl=es#multiple-apks)

Te sugiero leer también:

[Configurar Android-Studio para quitar código que no se usa en Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/23746/configurar-android-studio-para-quitar-c%c3%b3digo-que-no-se-usa-en-android/23803#23803)

[Buena resolución de imagen causa "OutOfMemoryError"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6343/buena-resoluci%c3%b3n-de-imagen-causa-outofmemoryerror)